# Setting Vendor Specific Css with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to apply transition rules to elements with javascript, so far this works for webkit:

```
this.self.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3D('+(d+this.position)+'px,0px,0)'
```

what are the other vendor specific property names? 
'webkitTransform' as for mozilla specific, opera etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox uses the case-sensitive `MozTransform`, Opera is `OTransform`, and IE9 uses `msTransform`. I don't think the other IE browsers use it, but they may be covered by the general `transform`.

See also [this page](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html).